# How to unset specific session in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three major roles here.

1. Owner
2. Moderator
3. Editor

Owner can sign out any moderators and editors.

I set moderator session like this :

```
$session_array = array(
   'sess_name' => $name,
   'sess_username' => $username,
   'sess_id' => $id
)

$this->session->set_userdata('moderator',$session_array);
```

For example, if there are Bob and Charlie log in as moderator, how can I sign Bob out, but not Charlie ?

---

This is not working

```
$data = array(
  'sess_name' => "bob",
  'sess_username' => "bob_imoet"
)

$this->session->unset_userdata($data);
```

This is also not working properly

```
$data = array(
  'sess_name' => "bob",
  'sess_username' => "bob_imoet"
)

$this->session->unset_userdata('moderator',$data);
```

Comment: check below answer...

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error with your array. The `,` comman is missing.

Try

```
$data = array(
  'sess_name' => "bob",
  'sess_username' => "bob_imoet"
)

$this->session->unset_userdata($data);
```

**Note: -** You need to load Session library first. `$this->load->library('session');`

Or you can do it core PHP

Try

```
unset($_SESSION['sess_name']);
unset($_SESSION['sess_username']);
```

**Note: -** You need to start Sessions. `session_start();`

Comment: @ZainabSafiyyahAl-habsyi can you attach any screenshot?

Comment: I don't know what to screenshot since it doesn't effect anything.. The moderator just can't be signed out..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
<?php
$data = array('sess_name','sess_username');  //array of items that you want to unset

$this->session->unset_userdata($data);
```

Comment: So it should be array('Bob', 'bob_imoet'); ?

Comment: session are always unset using names not values.So not need to make array of values.Just make array of names that you want to unset.

Comment: I don't wanna unset my current session.. I want to unset other user session.